# Azure Mlflow Run id not found using Python SDK azure-ai-ml v2

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow, azure-python-sdk

I'm using Azure ML jobs to run an experiment using python sdk-v2, and I haven't be able to access into the run logs after the run is completed. I'm not sure what is happening, if I'm missing some permission or a previous step. It just says "run 'xxxx' not found

```
from mlflow.tracking import MlflowClient

# Use MlFlow to retrieve the job that was just completed
run_id = 'musing_steelpan_xxxx'

finished_mlflow_run = MlflowClient().get_run(run_id)
```

.
The run_id actually exist, I'm the owner of the worspace and cluster.

```
MlflowException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [5], line 6
      3 # Use MlFlow to retrieve the job that was just completed
      4 run_id = 'musing_steelpan_hnlbhxf9qy'
----> 6 finished_mlflow_run = MlflowClient().get_run(run_id)

File /miniconda/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/client.py:150, in MlflowClient.get_run(self, run_id)
    112 def get_run(self, run_id: str) -> Run:
    113     """
    114     Fetch the run from backend store. The resulting :py:class:`Run <mlflow.entities.Run>`
    115     contains a collection of run metadata -- :py:class:`RunInfo <mlflow.entities.RunInfo>`,
   (...)
    148         status: FINISHED
    149     """
--> 150     return self._tracking_client.get_run(run_id)

File /miniconda/envs/benchmark/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/_tracking_service/client.py:72, in TrackingServiceClient.get_run(self, run_id)
     58 """
     59 Fetch the run from backend store. The resulting :py:class:`Run <mlflow.entities.Run>`
     60 contains a collection of run metadata -- :py:class:`RunInfo <mlflow.entities.RunInfo>`,
  (...)
     69          raises an exception.
     70 """
     71 _validate_run_id(run_id)
   ...
    648     )
    649 run_info = self._get_run_info_from_dir(run_dir)
    650 if run_info.experiment_id != exp_id:

MlflowException: Run 'musing_steelpan_xxxx' not found
```

Comment: What type of run is this? And where did you get the run_id from?

Comment: I'm running an Azure ML training Job, you can check reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-model?tabs=python) and the run_id was extracted from the Azure Portal workspace where the run was executed.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (e.g. for jobs inside a pipeline, jobs inside a sweep), the `display_name` shown at the top in the portal (which can be changed by the user) is not the same as the `name` of the job (which is immutable) and shown further down in the portal (see image below).

[image]

Did you take the `name` or the `display_name` from the portal (or are they the same)?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the help, but the name indeed is the same. I even use the properties json file to check it. I feel I'm missing some permission to access the Run, but I can't find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea: You might not be connected to the right workspace. You set the workspace by means of the MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI or as a direct parameter to the mlflow client. Try going to the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) and look at the workspace properties -- there you find the **MLFLow Tracking URI** for the workspace:

[image]

Then you can plug it into the code below -- this should print out 100 runs of your workspace (I believe the first 100...):

```py
client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient(tracking_uri="<your mlflow tracking uri>")
runs = client.search_runs(experiment_ids=[])
for run in runs:
    print(run.info.run_uuid)
```

For the above code to work you need to:

1. `pip install mlflow azureml-mlflow azureml-core`
2. `az login`